# Use of MySQL explain

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, explain

I have this query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT DISTINCT 
 PMS_STAGIONI.DINIZVAL,
 PMS_STAGIONI.DFINEVAL,
 PMS_DISPO.DDATA
FROM 
  PMS_DISPO JOIN PMS_STAGIONI
HAVING
  PMS_DISPO.DDATA BETWEEN PMS_STAGIONI.DINIZVAL AND PMS_STAGIONI.DFINEVAL
```

The output of explain is:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key                          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PMS_STAGIONI | index | NULL          | IDX_INIZFINEVAL_PMS_STAGIONI | 6       | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PMS_DISPO    | index | NULL          | IDX_DDATA_PMS_DISPO          | 3       | NULL | 1199 |   100.00 | Using index; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

My question is how to calculate the product of the join using explain. For example, in this case are performed 3597 (1199x3) scans or only 1199?

1)If I add "ORDER BY DDATA" lines scanned in the table "PMS_DISPO" become 1130.

2)If I use the "WHERE" clause instead of "HAVING" clause scan no longer uses the indexes. How is it possible?

3)If i want show PMS_STAGIONI.CSTAGIONI (primary key) explain show me that:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PMS_STAGIONI | ALL   | NULL          | NULL                | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | Using temporary                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PMS_DISPO    | index | NULL          | IDX_DDATA_PMS_DISPO | 3       | NULL | 1130 |   100.00 | Using index; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

How can I force the use of the other index?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

The structure of "PMS_DISPO" is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PMS_DISPO` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `CPRENOTA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DDATA` date NOT NULL,
  `CCATRIS` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `NQUANT` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `CAZIENDA` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `CAFFILIATO` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `IDX_DDATA_PMS_DISPO` (`DDATA`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1084 ;
```

And "PMS_STAGIONI" is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PMS_STAGIONI` (
  `CSTAGIONE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NVALIDI` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `BECCEZIONE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `AGGSET` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DINIZVAL` date NOT NULL,
  `DFINEVAL` date NOT NULL,
  `CAZIENDA` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `CSTAGIONE` (`CSTAGIONE`),
  KEY `IDX_INIZFINEVAL_PMS_STAGIONI` (`DINIZVAL`,`DFINEVAL`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: Can we see the other EXPLAIN, and SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't actually think it's possible to determine the number of scans from this information.

Comment: What is the criteria for determining if I'm actually doing the right things? Just the fact that use indexes?

Comment: That's a "cross join" !  You are getting _all_ combinations of _all_ rows from each table.  Only then does it filter out some (via `HAVING`).

Comment: Oh.  But it can't be improved a lot...  `WHERE x.a BETWEEN y.start AND y.end` cannot be optimized much.

Comment: You can't get much better than an _average_ of 1199x3/2.  The "/2" assumes you can start somewhere in the middle of the index.

Answer (score 0):

A query of this sort would normally be written as follows, with indexes just as you have them...

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.dinizval
              , s.dfineval
              , d.ddata
           FROM pms_dispo d
           JOIN pms_stagioni s
             ON d.ddata BETWEEN s.dinizval AND s.dfineval
```

Comment: The problem is that: if I use "Join ... On ..." without cstagione (primary Key) is ok... if I use cstagione in select MySQL use cstagione for join but i want use ddata! How I Can resolve?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: You can `ON` anything.

Comment: if I use this query I get the following result:

 1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ALL   | IDX_DDATA_PMS_DISPO          | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL | 1069 |   100.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2)